# Inherit from python's 'File' class and define custom behavior - python2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to customize the behavior of file handles in a library meant for both `python 2.7` and `python 3.x` (at least `>=3.6`).

The custom behavior I am implementing requires that something be done when the `close` method is called, either directly (`fh.close()`) or as a result of the `__exit__()` method.

I am also attempting to add an additional method - lets call it `custom_copy()`.

My ideal world is to give my users a file handle which they can use normally (read/readlines/write/...), but also has some special logic behind the scenes.

Here is what I am currently working with...

```
from os import fsync    

def custom_open(filepath, mode='rt', *args **kwargs):                                            

    # Open the file normally using open_args                                    
    orig_file_handle = open(filepath, mode, *args, **kwargs)  # pylint: disable=star-args                                 

    # Preserve original close function                                                                            
    original_close_fn = orig_file_handle.close                                  

    # Create a custom close function                                            
    def custom_close_fn(*args, **kwargs):                                       
        original_close_fn(*args, **kwargs)                                      
        print("Do Something Custom")                                            
    orig_file_handle.close = custom_close_fn                                    

    # Add custom_copy function                                                                    

    def custom_copy_fn(*args, **kwargs):                                    
        if orig_file_handle.closed:                                         
            raise ValueError("I/O operation on closed file")                

        # Ensure buffer has been flushed before rsync                       
        orig_file_handle.flush()                                            
        fsync()                                                             
        return _my_custom_copy(filepath, *args, **kwargs)                   
    orig_file_handle.custom_copy = custom_copy_fn                           

    return orig_file_handle
```

The above code works in `python3.7.0`, however in `python2.7.8` it fails with

```
>       orig_file_handle.close = custom_close_fn
E       AttributeError: 'file' object attribute 'close' is read-only
```

I have also tried another method involving SubClassing `type(orig_file_handle)`, however there are some other issues with that...

```
def custom_open(filepath, mode='rt', open_args=None):                          
    open_args = open_args or {}                                                
    open_args['mode'] = mode                                                   

    # Open the file normally using open_args                                   
    orig_file_handle = open(filepath, **open_args)  # pylint: disable=star-args

    class CustomFile(type(orig_file_handle)):                                  
        def __init__(self, file_handle):                                       
            # pylint: disable=super-init-not-called                            
            self.__dict__ = file_handle.__dict__.copy()                        

        def close(self, *args, **kwargs):                                      
            # Execute normal file handle close                                 
            super(CustomFile, self).close(*args, **kwargs)                     

            print("Do Something Custom")                                       

        def custom_copy(self, *args, **kwargs):                                
            if self.closed:  # pylint: disable=no-member                       
                raise ValueError("I/O operation on closed file")               

            self.flush()  # pylint: disable=no-member                          
            fsync()                                                            
            return _my_custom_copy(filepath, *args, **kwargs)                  

    return CustomFile(orig_file_handle)
```

In `python2.7.8` this fails with

```
>       self.__dict__ = file_handle.__dict__.copy()
E       AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

And in `python3.7.0` it fails with

```
>       self.__dict__ = file_handle.__dict__.copy()
E       AttributeError: attribute '__dict__' of '_io._IOBase' objects is not writable
```

Any ideas how to work around this, or are there other patterns I should be following to get my desired result?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Do not inherit, decorate:

```
class CustomFile:                                  
        def __init__(self, file_handle):                                       
            # pylint: disable=super-init-not-called                            
            self._f = file_handle                       

        def close(self, *args, **kwargs):                                      
            self._f.close(*args,**kwargs)   
            print("Do Something Custom")
            self.closed = True
```

**EDIT**

[This recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/) about proxying objects is good too

Comment: This isnt really what I'm going for - I'd like the object to still be a `~drop-in~' replacement for the built-in `open`, with some extra logic on `close()`

Comment: You can use `__getattribute__` to proxy all other calls to the actual file object.